# Is there a formula for general induction?

Tags: proof-verification, induction

When I read about mathematical induction, there is no general formula, just a notion that is described:

> Show true for $n = 1$
>
> Assume true for $n = k$
>
> Show true for $n = k + 1$
>
> Conclusion: Statement is true for all $n \geq 1$

Can we formalize the above notion into a "pluggable" formula where we just plug in the values of what we want to prove?

Comment: What do you mean by "values of what we want to prove"? Actually we want to prove of a certain property that each positive integer has this property.

Comment: What you state *is* a schema into which you can plug a property to be proved. To prove the implication $P(n) \implies P(n + 1)$ is the hearth, and often requires non-trivial insight. No royal road here, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any formula would depend on the specific case.

[In logic notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction),

> Mathematical induction as an inference rule can be formalized as a
> second-order axiom. The axiom of induction is, in logical symbols,
>
> $$\forall P.\,[[ P(0)\land \forall (k\in \mathbb {N}).\,[P(k)\Rightarrow P(k+1)]]\Rightarrow \forall (n\in \mathbb {N}).\,P(n)]$$
>
> where $P$ is any predicate and $k$ and $n$ are both natural numbers.

Comment: If this is what the OP is looking for then I think that $P$ is "pluggable" here.

Comment: I was thinking of how to formalize the statement "this is how you make a proof by induction"

Comment: @Programmer400 you can say "we will prove our claim by means of mathematical induction".